# Hibernate Generated fields null until flush

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to save an entity with multiple fields generated by DB triggers.

```
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected UUID id;

    //generated by DB trigger   
    @Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    @Column(name = "generated_number", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String generatedNumber;

    //generated by DB trigger
    @Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Column(name = "postfix", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer postfix;

   //other normal fields
}

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, UUID>, JpaRepository<MyEntity, UUID>
```

Documentation states that Generated annotation marks fields as filled by DB. Hibernate ought to load generated data from DB.

> Generated properties are properties that have their values generated
> by the database. Typically, Hibernate applications needed to refresh
> objects that contain any properties for which the database was
> generating values. Marking properties as generated, however, lets the
> application delegate this responsibility to Hibernate. **When
> Hibernate issues an SQL INSERT or UPDATE for an entity that has
> defined generated properties, it immediately issues a select to
> retrieve the generated values.**
>
> Properties marked as generated must additionally be non-insertable and
> non-updateable. Only @Version and @Basic types can be marked as
> generated.

However, the content of generated fields is not loaded until flush.

```
@Transactional
public MyEntity save(MyEntity entity) {
    //save without flush
    //assertions fail
    //MyEntity updated = repository.save(entity);
    //works fine
    MyEntity updated = repository.saveAndFlush(entity);
    assert updated.getGeneratedNumber() != null;
    assert updated.getPostfix() != null;
}
```

My generated fields are marked as non-insertable and non-updatable. They are of a basic String type. I also tried adding a `@Basic` annotation above them, but it wasn't helpful.

What am I missing?

Comment: Actually, as you can see from the examples in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-Generated), the `entityManager.flush();` method is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually because of caching, call to the database is performed actually when the transaction finishes. You are using `@Transactional` attribute, so that call is performed at the end of the method exactly by `flush()`, more specifically done internally by `commit()`. That is why you don't see the changes in code and the values are not generated - the call to the db was not done, before `flush()`.